# grief about the routeless nature of existence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "grief" here mean "sadness"? (sadness of the fact that the nature of existence has no pattern or map?)

> The presentation of randomised collections – often in the style of the wunderkammer, the cabinets of curiosity displayed by the early natural philosophers – is a favoured way of reflecting a delight in nature and in human existence, tinged with more than a little irony to suggest the foolhardiness of any belief in fixed hierarchies and taxonomies and also to imply an underlying **grief** about the routeless nature of existence.

(from a book titled *Art and Science* by Sîan Ede, describing an art exhibit)

Comment: Doesn't *grief* usually mean *sadness*? And should it be *rootless* or *routeless*? It's usually *rootless existence*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rootless+existence%2C+routeless+existence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crootless%20existence%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Apparently (according to Wikipedia) "Grief is a multifaceted response to loss"; as well as sadness its definition also include woe, desolation, despair, etc. Another multi-faceted (but non-English) word is *[dukkha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukkha)*.

Comment: @PeterShor The original of that quote says "routeless".

Comment: @ChrisW: I suspect that "routeless" is either a mistake or a pun.

Comment: @PeterShor I thought it mean trackless or unchartable, given the context that making taxonomies is foolhardy.

Comment: @ChrisW:  it's still a pun: *"rootless existence"* is an established expression, and I suspect the author is playing off it.

Comment: @Peter: Bearing in mind "nature red in tooth and claw" and all that, I'd have thought [***ruthless** nature of existence*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ruthless+nature+of+existence%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) was more likely. At least that one does actually occur a couple of times in Google Books.

Comment: As the comments here attest, this passage has no discernible meaning in the sense that it doesn't matter whether the "right" word is "trackless," "rootless," or "ruthless." Substitute "tinged with more than a little ennui to suggest the boldness of any belief in fixed hierarchies and taxonomies and also to deny an underlying despair about the gormless nature of existence."  Does that more any less sense than the original?  Could you even tell which was which if you didn't know I'd made it up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25947/discussion-between-deadrat-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: If [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259373/as-the-marxist-critic-herbert-marcuse-has-proposed/259382#259382) is any indication, trying to interpret Ede grammatically is doomed. I'm going to keep out of this one.

Comment: Author wanted something a little stronger than **ennui** and chose, perhaps, poorly?

Answer (score 1):

Grief may mean "sadness" here, but not necessarily: because "grief" can also mean trouble – for example, "he gave me grief" means "he gave me trouble".

Given that (it says), "the nature of existence makes it foolhardy to believe in fixed hierarchies", then creating those hierarchies isn't necessarily "sad" but might rather be "troublesome" or "difficult" (or more-or-less impossible) – perhaps a *Sisyphean* task.

Comment: I think you were on the right track in your comments above, when interpreting "routeless" to mean "trackless".  Routeless suggests random changes of direction.  I think we can understand "underlying grief" in the same context--a feeling of loss and emptiness in response to the apparent meaninglessness of what had long been regarded as intentional "design".

Comment: @TimRomano "Trackless" means there are no designated paths.  Why can't  "routeless" mean a refusal to select one of those? If you selected an undesignated path, why would it necessarily have to include "random changes"?  Where does Ede suggest that the meaninglessness (or whatever it is) is apparent and not real or that intentionality is involved?  What's the difference between design and "design"?

Comment: @deadrat: In the phrase "the routeless nature of existence" there is no implication whatsoever of anyone refusing to do anything. Rather it means Nature does not have routes, that is, tNature does not choose preordained paths as there are no such paths to be taken. From that sense of pathlessness it's but a stone's throw to randomness.  "Apparent" does not necessarily mean unreal; it means "as it appears to us". It does imply that knowledge is bounded. The quotation marks I put around *design* are a shorthand reference to the *opinion* that Nature evinces the intentions of a Designer.

Comment: Are either of you making some suggestion towards improving my answer?

Comment: @TimRomano When you interpret "routeless" to mean "trackless," you're saying that there are no paths.  I'm saying that "routeless" could well mean that there are paths, but our "existence" allows us not to choose any of them.  Everything you say is a reasonable interpretation of the text, but then so is everything else.  That's the nature of the writing of postmodernist culture theory.

Comment: @ChrisW Look at your answer -- "perhaps," "if," "isn't necessarily," "perhaps" (again).  There's nothing wrong with your answer, but like all interpretations of the idiosyncratic language of culture theory, it is itself idiosyncratic.  No other answer will be an improvement; it will just be different.

Comment: @deadrat: I'm saying that for Ede,  "no fixed hierarchies"  and "routeless existence" are analogous metaphors for the randomness of natural selection.

Comment: @TimRomano Could be.  It would be better to say that for *you* Ede's text means something about natural selection.  You might even be right.

Comment: @deadrat: We don't need to say IMO every time we offer an opinion, just as a no-hunting sign should not have to say "posted":  `POSTED: NO HUNTING`.

Comment: @TimRomano Pretty much my point:  if Ede's text used language in a way in the standard, (mostly) accessible way, there would be no need to hedge.  Two people who disagreed about an interpretation could use a grammar and a dictionary to settle their differences.  But that's not possible here.  All cultural theory writing should be accompanied by a warning:  POSTED: NO MEANING.

Comment: @deadrat The piece is a description of a work of art (exhibited in the Tate). Is that what "cultural theory writing" is, i.e. written descriptions of art?

Comment: @ChrisW No, you're thinking of art criticism.  Cultural theory is a branch of semiotics that is the supposedly rigorous study of how society determines meaning through language, art and science.  One of its propositions is that art and science use the same interpretive lens.  Practitioners employ language in such a bizarre way, and they are so breathtakingly ignorant of the science they discuss, that nothing they write has any discernible sense.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they author is describing 'frustration' or 'annoyance'

> **grief**
>   : trouble or annoyance
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grief

Comment: You might try spelling it correctly.

Comment: That would help. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Routeless" makes sense in the above, when you consider it to mean "aimless" or "random", with no "map", no "guiding hand".  This sense is mirroring the use of "randomized" at the start of the excerpt.  (I see no intent to form a pun here.)

The "grief" is a sadness because the "routelessness" implies that there is no overriding "scheme" or "plan".  Many scientists would like to believe that such a master plan exists and might eventually be discerned with sufficient research, but the writer is saying this won't happen.